# Need two marquees, but they keep cloning

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm very new to jQuery and apologize in advance if the answer is, as I suspect, very simple.

I've been trying to get two marquees to run, one under the other. However, they keep cloning and so I end up with four. How can I solve this issue?

My html document looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.marquee.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('.marquee').marquee({
                //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
                speed: 350000,
                //gap in pixels between the tickers
                gap: 50,
                //gap in pixels between the tickers
                delayBeforeStart: 0,
                //'left' or 'right'
                direction: 'left'
            });
        }); 
</script>
<style type="text/css">
        body {
          font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
          color: #FFF;
          background-color: #333;
        }

        .marquee {
margin-top: 150px;
width: 1580px;
overflow: hidden;
border:0px;
line-height:300px;
font-size:64pt;
vertical-align: top;
position: absolute;
left: 11px;
        }

        .marquee p {    
        margin-top: 10px;
        line-height:100px;
        }

        price {
            font-size:54pt; 
            color: #CCC;
            vertical-align: baseline;
            font-size: 54pt;
            position: relative;
            bottom: -50pt;
        }
</style>
<title>  </title>
</head>

<body>
<div class='marquee'>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

AAPL<price>586.92 <img src="down.png"> -9.62</price> 
GOOG<price>690.00 <img src="up.png"> +2.41</price> 
IBM<price>195.3375 <img src="down.png"> -1.81</price> 
MSFT<price>29.695 <img src="up.png"> +0.18</price> 
AMZN<price>234.60 <img src="up.png"> +2.46</price> 
PM<price>87.67 <img src="up.png"> +0.08</price> 
QCOM<price>59.67 <img src="down.png"> -0.06</price> 
SLB<price>69.25 <img src="down.png"> -0.90</price> 
ORCL<price>31.50 <img src="up.png"> +0.02</price> 
KO<price>37.3067 <img src="down.png"> -0.02</price> 
XOM<price>90.56 <img src="down.png"> -1.02</price> 
PFE<price>24.82 <img src="up.png"> +0.27</price> 
GE<price>21.4799 <img src="up.png"> +0.14</price> 
CVX<price>108.66 <img src="down.png"> -2.80</price> 

<p>

FITB<price>14.45 <img src="down.png"> -0.11</price> 
DFS<price>41.35 <img src="up.png"> +0.03</price> 
EIX<price>47.02 <img src="up.png"> +0.31</price> 
GRA<price>66.09 <img src="up.png"> +0.28</price> 
M<price>40.95 <img src="up.png"> +0.43</price> 
AON<price>55.18 <img src="up.png"> +0.38</price> 
BXP<price>107.16 <img src="up.png"> +0.70</price> 
CNP<price>21.69 <img src="down.png"> -0.05</price> 
NBL<price>95.07 <img src="down.png"> -0.33</price> 
APC<price>70.68 <img src="up.png"> +0.34</price> 
AYI<price>64.69 <img src="down.png"> -1.40</price> 
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The jQuery marquee script I'm referring to above (jquery.marquee.js) is Aamir Afridi's, see below:

```
/**
 * jQuery.marquee - scrolling text horizontally
 * Date: 11/01/2013
 * @author Aamir Afridi - aamirafridi(at)gmail(dot)com | http://www.aamirafridi.com
 * @version 1.0
 */

;(function($) {
$.fn.marquee = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        // Extend the options if any provided
        var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.marquee.defaults, options),
            $this = $(this),
            $marqueeWrapper,
            elWidth;

        //check if element has data attributes. They have top priority
        o = $.extend({}, o, $this.data());

        //wrap inner content into a div
        $this.wrapInner('<div class="js-marquee"></div>');

        //Make copy of the element
        $this.find('.js-marquee').css({
            'margin-right': o.gap, 
            'float':'left'
        }).clone().appendTo($this);

        //wrap both inner elements into one div
        $this.wrapInner('<div style="width:100000px" class="js-marquee-wrapper"></div>');

        //Save the width of the each element so we can use it in animation
        elWidth = $this.find('.js-marquee:first').width() + o.gap;

        //Save the reference of the wrapper
        $marqueeWrapper = $this.find('.js-marquee-wrapper');

        //Animate recursive method
        var animate = function() {
            //Move to zero possition
            $marqueeWrapper.css('margin-left', o.direction == 'left' ? 0 : '-' + elWidth + 'px');
            //Start animating to wards left
            $marqueeWrapper.animate({
                    'margin-left': o.direction == 'left' ? '-' + elWidth + 'px' : 0
                },
                o.speed, 'linear',
                animate
            );
        };

        //Starts the recursive method
        setTimeout(animate, o.delayBeforeStart);

    });
};//End of Plugin

// Public: plugin defaults options
$.fn.marquee.defaults = {
    //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
    speed: 10000,
    //gap in pixels between the tickers
    gap: 20,
    //gap in pixels between the tickers
    delayBeforeStart: 1000,
    //'left' or 'right'
    direction: 'left'
};
})(jQuery);
```

You can see it in action [here](http://lilyjen.com/investors/exhibition-ticker/index.html).

Thanks so much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four rows because your content is too wide for the width you set and also too wide for the width the plugin uses in its container div. So it's wrapping around and giving you extra rows. You can change your marque class to this:

```
.marquee {
  margin-top: 150px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:0px;
  line-height:300px;
  font-size:64pt;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: absolute;
  left: 11px;
}
```

I took out your `width` and added `white-space: nowrap`, so your text does not wrap and flow down your page vertically. Also, in the plugin code you need to change this line:

```
//wrap both inner elements into one div
$this.wrapInner('<div style="width:100000px" class="js-marquee-wrapper"></div>');
```

To this:

```
//wrap both inner elements into one div
$this.wrapInner('<div class="js-marquee-wrapper"></div>');
```

You can remove the width style completely and it appears to work fine. If you'd rather not edit the plugin code, you can also add this style to override the width:

```
.js-marquee-wrapper {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you again for your help, really made my day!

Comment: Yea good answer exactly what i was about to say before i realized you had already posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed this plugin. This is designed to have simple content to scroll. I can see that you have many elements including `<p>` which has `display:block` by default so this makes the content push to next line.

Simplest solution is to add this to your css:

```
.marquee p {
  display: inline;
}
```

See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/R464v/2/

So on your demo:

```
.marquee p {    
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height:100px;
    display: inline; /* <============ ADD THIS TO YOUR CSS */
}
```

That should the trick ;)

I have made your example simpler by removing some html but kept the same structure. [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/R464v/6/)